# Error in simple dynamic List C

Tags: c, xcode

I'm trying to do a function that returns me the k-th element of a dynamic list but I'm getting an error called

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1,address=0x0)

This is the code :

I know this may be a really dumb/noob question, but I really don't get what's the problem, because I just started learning pointers and "strange" things of C

## code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct elemento{    
    int edad;
}elemento;

typedef struct Nodo{

    struct Nodo *siguiente;
    elemento info;

}Nodo;

typedef struct grafo{

    Nodo *primero;
    Nodo *ultimo;
    int largo;

}grafo;

Nodo *crear_nodo(elemento info){

    Nodo *n=malloc(sizeof(Nodo));
    n->info=info;
    n->siguiente=NULL;
    return n;
}

grafo *nuevo_grafo(){

    grafo *g=malloc(sizeof(grafo));
    g->primero=NULL;
    g->ultimo=NULL;
    g->largo=0;
    return g;

}

void Agregar_nodo(grafo *g, elemento info){

    Nodo *n=crear_nodo(info);
    if (g->largo==0) {
        g->primero=n;
        g->ultimo=n;
        g->largo=1;
    }

    else{
    
        g->ultimo=n;
        g->largo=+1;
    
    }
};

elemento encontrar_elemento_k(Nodo *primero, int k){

    for (int i=0; i<k; k++) {
        primero=(primero->siguiente);  \\In this line Xcode is indicating the error
    }
    elemento data=primero->info;

    return data;
    
}
```

Comment: It would seem `k` doesn't reflect the number of items actually in the list. If that is indeed the location where the process breaks, you're dereferencing a NULL pointer, which means `k` is overstating your node count.

Comment: In Agregar_nodo you need to set the next pointer (siguiente) to the previous head of the list (primero). At least if you want to append to the front.